# POST multiple inputs using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two input fields (user-name and lguser) and i want to send all field values to php page, i can just send user-name value. Please help

```
<script>
   // AJAX call for autocomplete 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#user-name").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphppage.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#user-name").css("background","#FFF url(../assets/media/image/loadings.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#user-name").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});
//To select country name
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#user-name").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>


 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" name="user-name" >
<input type="hidden" value="lguser" id="lguser">
```

Comment: I suggest you look into debouncing too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
 data:'keyword='+$(this).val()+'&lguser='+$('#lguser').val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you use   data:'keyword='+$(this).val()
here (this) get value form ** $("#user-name").keyup(function(){** 
means get value only user-name

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the values of both inputs and store them in an object. Then assign that object as the `data` property of the `$.ajax()`. jQuery will send that data as JSON, which you'll have to deserialize on the PHP side.

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
    keyword: $('#user-name').val(),
    lguser: $('#lguser').val(),
  }
})
```

Alternatively, put your inputs in a `<form>` element and use `jquery.serialize()` to serialize all inputs into a query string, with the `name` property of each element as key.

```
const formData = $('#the-form').serialize()

$.ajax({
  data: {
    url: `myphppage.php?${formData}`
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send data in ajax request like this

data: {'username': $('#user-name'.val()), 'userid': $('#lguser').val()}